# Usage of nan desu?

Tags: particles, questions, contractions, nominalization

In a few songs I've heard recently I've noticed that *なんです（nan desu）* (without the か) has been used in what seems to be maybe a declarative or emphatic sense (not really sure), is this possible?

I'm not overly familiar with usage of *nan desu* outside of it being used in the question sense (i.e. *なんですか　nan desu ka*). If someone could clarify uses of *nan desu* I would be super appreciative.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is なのです (often contracted to なんです), which fits the bill. Just like you suspect, it is declarative/emphatic.

This なんです is unrelated to 何{なん}です, but rather a combination of な (the inflection of the copula だ, if you like), the nominalizer の plus the "politifier" です.

It also exists in non-polite form: なのだ・なんだ.

It really appears everywhere, e.g. as a conjunction なので or question marker ～なんですか. (Again, unrelated to 何.)

Comment: Very informative, thanks for the clarification!