# What does なんです mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation

> あの、考古学者**なんです**が、インディ・ジョーンズみたいな帽子を被ってなくてすいません。

Although I *am* an archeologist...? (Although I assure you that I am an archeologist...)

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xs-XWk_oQA
0:23

Comment: Also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14565/usage-of-nan-desu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the なんです functions exactly like

> んです (which isn't used here due to grammar restrictions)

So basically, he wants to say 'Although I *am* an archaeologist, I do not wear a hat like Indiana Jones'. He assumes that the viewers might have the misconception that all archaeologists wear hats, just because Indiana Jones (who might be the only famous archaeologist they know, and hence the misconception) does.

In other words, that archaeologist thinks that (to the general public) being an archaeologist **implies** that he wears a hat like Indiana Jones.

You may read this page for more examples on ~なんです・んです:

http://www.japanese-language.aiyori.org/article10.html

Comment: Great comment and article thanks.