# What does 「学生さんなんですか」 mean?

Tags: translation

> 学生さんなんですか？

Is she asking the name of the school I go to or what year I'm in? She was talking about how busy she's been at work and I told her I was busy with my studies as well and she replied with this.

Comment: The 何 is a typo for なん. 「学生なんですか？」 "Are you a student?"

Comment: she actually wrote「 学生さんなんですか？」

Comment: I think she was asking, Are you a student?

Answer (score 6):

As @choco points out in the comment section, 何 is a typo for なん (ん being a contraction of の).

You can read more about なんです(か) here:

- [The difference between [noun phrase]+[？・なの？・ですか？・なんですか？]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18400/the-difference-between-noun-phrase-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)
- [What does なんです mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29342/what-does-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-mean-in-this-sentence)
- [Usage of nan desu?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14565/usage-of-nan-desu/14566#14566)

Comment: But would it really be a typo? I would argue more a colloquial writing choice that a typographical error. From the times I have asked writers of similar, it is usually a conscious effort to not use the Kanji / to use hiragana instead (as for reasoning, there has been everything from trying to be more cute, trying to avoid Kanji and just a preference for it.).

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder The typo is that the kanji was used, not that it wasn't. This なん comes from なの; the one spelt 何 comes from なに.

Comment: Apologies, there was no Kanji when I got to the question. It was a little bit confusing. I will endeavour to check question edits better next time.