# How do the は and が function here?

Tags: meaning, copula, は-and-が, no-da

> 受験生は夏休みが勝負なのよ?

So since there is no verb here, how do the は and が function here?

Comment: Do you recognize な as the copula だ?

Comment: If you are asking how the structure of the sentence is composed, it's topicalizing 受験生 from either 受験生が夏休みが勝負 or 夏休みが受験生の勝負.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As you can see in [this chart](http://www.japaneseprofessor.com/reference/grammar/conjugations-of-the-japanese-copula/), な in なのよ is the attributive form of だ ("the copula"). And だ/です safely works as the predicate of a sentence. (e.g., 今日は日曜日です, 私は学生です)
- よ is a feminine sentence-end particle.
- Here both は and が are used in one sentence, and this can be understood in the same way as you interpret 私は猫が好きだ or 彼は背が高い.
- 勝負 here is a noun which means the same thing as [勝負【しょうぶ】所【どころ】](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%8B%9D%E8%B2%A0%E6%89%80), "critical point".

Therefore this sentence basically is a feminine version of 受験生は夏休みが勝負なのだ, which is an emphatic version of 受験生は夏休みが勝負だ.

> 受験生は夏休みが勝負だ
>   → As for test-takers, summer vacation is the critical point.
>   → Summer vacation is the most important term for students preparing for entrance exams.

References:

- [Usage of nan desu?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14565/5010)
- [What exactly is "なの" (nano)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/514/5010)
- [What is the meaning of ～んです?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010) — there is a good answer regarding (な)のよ, (な)のだ, (な)のです, etc.
- [私は猫が好き and 猫は私が好き](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17857/5010)
- [how could a sentence end with (noun + "よ"?)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12986/5010)

Answer (score 0):

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 322:
の: a sentence-final particle used by a female speaker or a child to indicate an explanation or emotive emphasis.
Examples:
母はまだとても元気なの。
主人はエンジニアなの。

So the translation could be:
夏休みが勝負なの。
Summer vacation is when the fight is decided.

The sentence above is identical to 
夏休みが勝負だ。

が is the subject marker.
は is the topic marker.

The full sentence is:
受験生は夏休みが勝負なのよ。
For the applicants, summer vacation is when the fight is decided.