# Meaning of 僕に in 「僕に勝手に人を裁く権利があるのか？」

Tags: translation

In the first episode of Death Note, the speaker wonders whether he has the right to take people's lives as he wishes:

> **僕に**勝手に人を裁く権利があるのか？

I understand that 勝手に means "as one pleases", but what nuance is 僕に adding? Does it mean "selfishly" ("for myself")?

Comment: Related: [The usage of particle「に」：彼女に孫が一人いる。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/75062/5010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this sentence down into its simplest part.

> 権利【けんり】があるのか？
> right [SUBJ] exists [EXPLANATORY] [QUESTION]?
> Is there the right [to do something]?

Note that ある can also be translated as "to have", if this verb is used in relation to a person.  The person "having" the thing is frequently marked with the topic particle は, as in 私【わたし】[は]{●}自転車【じてんしゃ】がある → "as for me, there is a bicycle / a bicycle exists" → "I have a bicycle".

The person can also be marked with the dative / locative particle に.  Translating the construction `[PERSON]`に`[THING]`がある might be a bit like "by [PERSON], there exists [THING]".  The phrasing is odd from an English-language point of view, but it isn't that uncommon in languages around the world -- we see close structural analogs in such far-flung languages as Hungarian, Navajo, and German.  Even English, in certain cases.

Adding the person in, we get:

> 僕【ぼく】に権利【けんり】があるのか？
> I [LOC] right [SUBJ] exists [EXPLANATORY] [QUESTION]?
> Is there the right [to do something] by me / in me?
> Do I have the right [to do something]?

And lastly, as I suspect you're already aware, the bit in the middle tells us specifically what kind of 権利【けんり】 or "right" we're talking about here -- the right to 勝手【かって】に人【ひと】を裁く【さばく】, or "freely judge people".

Comment: Thanks. It really clicked for me when you broke it down literally via "I [LOC] right [SUBJ] exists [COORDINATING] [QUESTION]?"  One last thing though: What do you mean by [COORDINATING] here?

Comment: @George -- This usage of の is a kind of coordinating explanatory usage. Translating this directly, it might be like "it is the case that / is it the case that ..." (depending on whether it shows up in a statement or a question).  One sec and I'll see if I can dig up a related thread or two.

Comment: @George -- ya, there's a lot to find: [search results for "explanatory の"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=explanatory+%E3%81%AE). There's also a separate but related post of mine [over here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66524/origin-of-the-usage-of-%e3%81%aa-in-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0/66541#66541), touching on the nominalization role played by の after verbs.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm familiar with the explanatory の, but just didn't know what why the word "COORDINATING" was associated with it.

Comment: @George -- Ah, that was a spur-of-the-moment choice, likely because I'd just been reading other threads about the use of の in coordinating clauses.  :)  On revisiting this post above, I see that that is indeed confusing, and I'll swap that out for "EXPLANATORY". Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 1):

The particle に here indicates a subject of possession, and it makes up the expression「(subject)に(object)がある」.